# No Json serializer as JsObject found for type play.api.libs.json.JsValue

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I'm trying to migrate my project from using `play2-reactivemongo` version `0.10.5.0.akka23` to using version `0.11.7.play23`. I've already added the following import to fix the problems addressed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31142366/no-json-serializer-as-jsobject-found-for-type-play-api-libs-json-jsobject):

```
import play.modules.reactivemongo.json._
```

With the former version, the following code worked:

```
val updateEntity = Json.obj("_id" -> Json.obj("$oid" -> id))
val entity = Json.parse(stringJson)
collection.update(updateEntity, entity)
```

however, using the new version, the third line gives a compile error:

```
[error] No Json serializer as JsObject found for type play.api.libs.json.JsValue. Try to implement an implicit OWrites or OFormat for this type.
[error]     collection.update(updateEntity, entity)
[error]                      ^
```

I've tried introducing an implicit `OWriter`:

```
implicit val toJsObject: OWrites[JsValue] = OWrites.apply(_.as[JsObject])
```

but that gives an implicit declaration conflict:

```
[error] ambiguous implicit values:
[error]  both value toJsObject of type play.api.libs.json.OWrites[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]
[error]  and object JsObjectDocumentWriter in trait ImplicitBSONHandlers of type play.modules.reactivemongo.json.JsObjectDocumentWriter.type
[error]  match expected type collection.pack.Writer[play.api.libs.json.JsObject]
[error]     collection.update(updateEntity, entity)
[error]                      ^
```

changing the second line to

```
val entity = Json.parse(stringJson).as[JsObject]
```

fixes the problem, but I have a lot of these around my code and I was hoping for a simpler solution.

Comment: Why not write a function like , `def parseJson(json: String) =  { Json.parse(json).as[JsObject] }`  and use this function instead.

Comment: @curious I was hoping for a magical import which would add the required implicit conversions which I'm missing. Creating the function you suggested would still require me to change all occurrences of `Json.parse` in my code, and with that I don't really see much advantage to just adding `.as[JsObject]` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Just got bit by this too.  The trick is to remove

```
import play.modules.reactivemongo.json._
```

and instead use

```
import reactivemongo.play.json._
```

The play.modules version doesn't provide the identity OWriter.