# No Json serializer as JsObject found for type model.User. Try to implement an implicit OWrites or OFormat for this type

Tags: scala, playframework, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I'm using Play framework with Scala and Reactive Mongo to save an object into my mongodb database. Following this http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.10/documentation/bson/usage.html I came up with the following code:

```
import java.util.Date

import com.google.inject.Inject
import model.User
import play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoApi
import play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONCollection
import reactivemongo.bson.{BSONDocument, BSONDocumentReader, BSONDocumentWriter, BSONObjectID}
import play.modules.reactivemongo.json._, ImplicitBSONHandlers._
import json.JsonFormatters._

class UserRepository @Inject() (val reactiveMongoApi : ReactiveMongoApi) {

  private def users = reactiveMongoApi.db.collection[JSONCollection]("users")

  def save(user: User) = {
    users.insert(user)
  }

  implicit object UserWriter extends BSONDocumentWriter[User] {
    def write(user: User) = {
      BSONDocument(
        "_id" -> Option(user.id).getOrElse(BSONObjectID.generate),
        "name" -> user.name,
        "email" -> user.email,
        "companyName" -> user.companyName,
        "created" -> Option(user.created).getOrElse(new Date)
      )
    }
  }

  implicit object UserReader extends BSONDocumentReader[User] {
    def read(doc: BSONDocument): User = {
      User(
        doc.getAs[BSONObjectID]("_id").get,
        doc.getAs[String]("name").get,
        doc.getAs[String]("email").get,
        doc.getAs[String]("companyName").get,
        doc.getAs[Date]("created").get
      )
    }
  }
}
```

I created my implicit writers to convert to a BsonDocument, so I was expecting it to be properly converted and saved into the database.

However, when I compile, I get:

```
UserRepository.scala:18: No Json serializer as JsObject found for type model.User. Try to implement an implicit OWrites or OFormat for this type.
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]     users.insert(user)
```

I'm importing necessary packages as mentioned in [No Json serializer as JsObject found for type play.api.libs.json.JsObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31142366/no-json-serializer-as-jsobject-found-for-type-play-api-libs-json-jsobject#).
I'm also importing json.JsonFormatters._ which includes:

```
implicit val userWrites : Format[User] = Json.format[User]
```

Yet, it's still returning the same error telling me it can't convert from JsObject to User. I fail to see where is the JsObject here, considering my User entity is just a case class with 5 fields.

```
case class User(var id: BSONObjectID, var name: String, var email: String, var companyName: String, var created: Date) {
}
```

Any ideas? What am I missing?

Comment: try defining implicit formatters in User companion object or import the implicits

Comment: 0.10 is an old version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using BSONObjectID, and you do not have implicit OFormat for that type. Try this:

```
implicit val format = Json.format[User]    
implicit val userFormats = new OFormat[User] {
override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[User] = format.reads(json)

override def writes(o: User): JsObject = format.writes(o).asInstanceOf[JsObject]
}
```

Typically, BSONObjectID (_id) does not make any sense in the application. Therefore, you should not use it. If you need an Id, for example as a running number, for users, you can define a new field. This is an example: https://github.com/luongbalinh/play-mongo/blob/master/app/models/User.scala