# No Json serializer as JsObject found for type play.api.libs.json.JsObject. Try to implement an implicit OWrites or OFormat for this type

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I am newbie to mongodb and also to reactive mongo and I'm trying to integrate this example to my project https://github.com/sgodbillon/reactivemongo-demo-app 
Firstly I would like to work only with class article but when I integrate the model and the controller I get this error:

```
No Json serializer as JsObject found for type play.api.libs.json.JsObject. Try to implement an implicit OWrites or OFormat for this type.
```

for this line in the controller:

```
63    // the cursor of documents
64    val found = collection.find(query).cursor[Article]
```

Comment: may be there is no implicit reader for `Article`?

Comment: Please show the contents of  `query`, this should be a `JsObject`.

Comment: Have you tried importing `import play.modules.reactivemongo.json._` as stated in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31142366/no-json-serializer-as-jsobject-found-for-type-play-api-libs-json-jsobject? Which version of reactivemongo are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Have you implement writes for `Article`?

simple macros must helps you

```
implicit val articleWrite = Json.writes[Article]
```

Comment: of course - I'm confused you need writes or format and not reads. I refine answer. You can implement own `OWrites` like `implicit val myWrites: OWrites[A] = new OWrites[A] { def writes(a: A) = Json.obj(...) }`