# What is the wrong while trying to parse Future response?

Tags: scala, http, playframework, response, future

I have a function which will take a Token via ajax request. It will return a response a list of directories while the token is valid.

```
def all = Action.async(parse.json) {
  implicit request => tokenForm.bind(request.body).fold(
    formWithErrors => Future.successful(BadRequest(formWithErrors.toString)),
    form => checkToken(form.token).map(token => {
      val directories = Directories.all.map(directory => {
        Json.toJson(directory)
      })
      Ok(Json.obj("status" -> {if (token.get.id.getOrElse(0) >= 1) true else false}, "message" -> {if (token.get.id.getOrElse(0) >= 1) Json.toJson(directories) else "Invalid token"}))
    })
  )
}
```

While I run the above code It says [As ^ sign indicate the position the error found]

```
No Json serializer found for type scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
Ok(Json.obj("status" -> {if (token.get.id.getOrElse(0) >= 1) true else false}, "message" -> {if (token.get.id.getOrElse(0) >= 1) Json.toJson(directories) else "Invalid token"}))
                                                                                                                                            ^
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31142366/no-json-serializer-as-jsobject-found-for-type-play-api-libs-json-jsobject) may help.

Comment: `if (<condition>) true else false` are you for real? :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I come up with

```
def all = Action.async(parse.json) {
  implicit request => tokenForm.bind(request.body).fold(
    formWithErrors => Future.successful(BadRequest(formWithErrors.toString)),
    form => for {
      (token, directories) <- checkToken(form.token) zip Directories.all
    } yield {
      val isTokenValid = token.isDefined
      val responseBody = Json.obj(
        "status" -> isTokenValid, 
        "message" -> {
          if (isTokenValid)
            Json.toJson(directories)
          else
            "Invalid token"
        }
      )
      Ok(responseBody)
    }
  )
}
```

asuming `checkToken` and `Directories.all` returns `Future`.

Your function needs to return `Future[Result]`. When you are folding, the first branch is correct

```
formWithErrors => Future.successful(BadRequest(formWithErrors.toString))
```

However in the second branch it seems like you started a new Future by calling `Directories.all`, and you want to serialize it and return as json. There is no serializer for `Future[JsValue]` as this makes no sense, it would have to block to get result. You need to somehow get to the values of both `checkToken(form.token)` and `Directories.all`.

You can do this as I did above, or for example like this:

```
form => {
  val futureToken = checkToken(form.token)
  val futureDirectories = Directories.all

  for {
    token <- futureToken
    directories <- futureDirectories
  } yield {
     // same code as above
  }
}
```

Notice that if you would inline `futureToken` and `futureDirectories` they would be executed serially.

Also note that you are converting your directory list to json twice.

Once here

```
val directories = Directories.all.map(directory => {
  Json.toJson(directory)
})
```

Asuming `Directories.all` returns `Future[List[Directory]]`, then when you use `map`, the function you pass operates on `List[Directory]` so the variable should be named `directories` not `directory`. It will work, play easly converts list of anything convertible to json, no need to do it manually.

Second time you did it here

```
Json.toJson(directories)
```

Comment: yes you are right ... `checkToken` and `Directories.all` both returns `Future`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea ... It works for me ... @Lukasz

Comment: I did a mistake with condition `val isTokenValid = token.get.id.getOrElse(0) >= 1`. It should be `token.isDefined` rather than `token.get.id.getOrElse(0) >= 1`. It through an exception while I put `token.get.id.getOrElse(0) >= 1` rather than `token.isDefined`.

Comment: You probably meant `token.map(_.id).getOrElse(0) >= 1`

Comment: You could probably also do `token.exists(_.id > 0)`