# Compilation error in Play framework

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am working on a login process using the Play framework and Scala and I am getting the following error:

```
No Json serializer as JsObject found for type play.api.libs.json.JsValue. Try to implement an implicit OWrites or OFormat for this type
```

Here is my model code. What am I doing wrong?

```
def checkUser(user: Signin): Future[Option[Signin]] = {
  val query = BSONDocument("_email" -> user.email, "password" -> user.password)
  collection.flatMap(_.find(query).requireOne[Signin])
}
```

Comment: Which mongo driver are you using? I don't see any use of `play.api.libs.json.JsValue`. It seems that your problem is somewhere else and not in the code which you shared.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No Json serializer as JsObject found for type play.api.libs.json.JsObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31142366/no-json-serializer-as-jsobject-found-for-type-play-api-libs-json-jsobject)